# Rails Specifying Conditions on Eager Loaded Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, eager-loading

I have Users and Todos models, users have many todos and todo belongs to user and I need to find users who created a todo in the last day, if there is then send them an email. I've tried the query from the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) but it doesn't return any records even though there are because of (I think) the date format:

`User.includes(:todos).where(todos: { created_at: 1.day.ago})`

I've also tried:

`User.includes(:todos).where(todos: { created_at: 1.day.ago.to_date})`

and

`User.includes(:todos).where(todos: { "date(created_at) = ?", 1.day.ago.to_date})`

but the last one doesn't work:
`SyntaxError: unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input`

I use Postgres, `created_at` is a datetime field (default rails timestamp)

in Psql:

`created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the specifications in the post , you need to get the todos created on the past day, so

the below mentioned query will not work

```
User.includes(:todos).where(todos: { created_at: 1.day.ago.to_date})
```

As 1.day.ago gives a particular timestamp and the database searches for the same timestamp ie including matching hours , minutes and seconds as well.

So a better approach would be to search for the timestamp covering the whole day and thus provide range would be the best option.

Modify the query as below mentioned:

```
User.includes(:todos).references(:todos).where("todos.created_at >= ? and todos.created_at <= ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, 1.day.ago.end_of_day)
```

This will fetch the todos created on the past day covering the whole day timings.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "todos"`

Comment: User.includes(:todos).references(:todos).where("todos.created_at >= ? and todos.created_at <= ?", 1.day.ago.beginning_of_day, 1.day.ago.end_of_day)
Modify with this query

Comment: The last query seems to have worked. I have also figured one which returns same results: `User.joins(:todos).where("date(todos.created_at) = ?", 1.day.ago.to_date).includes(:todos)`. Any idea what is happening here? :)

Comment: While the query which you have mentioned in the post uses the eager loading concept ie loading parent data and corresponding associated data in cache while the last one specified uses lazy loading ie loading only specified data

Comment: Thanx. Wouldn't it be better to cut the timestamp somehow only to year-month-day in the query so that we don't have to specfiy the range?

Comment: you can use that using strftime but created_at is datetime column so will be either needing to cast them based on year, month and day or you need to specify the range